# linker error in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I just started a new project in XCode and now what I got is this:
[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi It seems you are using Location Manager class in your project.Please add the CoreLocations framework in your project.

Comment: Off topic. Did you note EquinoX is also named Aditya :) ?

Comment: Ya i noticed that in the log ;)

Answer (score 1):

Pls make sure that the frameworks necessary for `CLLocation` is added to your project.